# Issue with China user connection to Salesforce db/server timing out

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

We use an in-house developed mobile app (similar to Veeva) that runs on iPads for our field force team. Users try to sync the app regularly to 1) get the latest data updates from the Salesforce db/server and 2) send updates to the Salesforce db/server. This mechanism has been running ok for the last 1.5 years. We do face errors but these are to do with issues with data / app exceptions and we have been able to handle them. In case of China users, we observe sync errors which hint at the connection to Salesforce db/server timing out … examples of the error logs attached (generated from our mobile app).

1. Sync completed at 100% with error, but no clear issue indicator in log. Sometimes retry works, but it fails more often.
2. Sync stopped at 2% or 35% with error, but no clear issue indicator in log. Sometimes retry works, but it fails more often.

Logs:

```
Device id: D11AD224-87F3-440E-828C-163CE6FC53DF
09.05.2019 11:16
OS version-iOS 11.4.1
App version-1.10.0
INFO 11:16:30:619-Synchronization started. Steps count: 9
INFO 11:16:40:811-Configuration received OK
INFO 11:16:48:520-User received 1 OK
INFO 11:16:52:652-Slide Configuration received 1 OK
INFO 11:16:54:742-Presentation Slide received 217 OK
INFO 11:16:57:301-Record Type received 342 OK
INFO 11:16:59:152-Target received 0 OK
INFO 11:17:01:510-Marketing Cycle received 0 OK
INFO 11:17:03:831-Marketing Message received 18 OK
INFO 11:18:04:684-Brick receiving FAIL. **Error message: undefined. Stack trace: undefined**
ERROR 11:18:04:689
"The request timed out."
INFO 11:18:04:744-Synchronization finished with error.
```

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Are you using SmartSync? Have you tried increasing the timeout interval?

Comment: https://engineering.salesforce.com/how-salesforce-optimizes-performance-in-china-9efad74f0884 China is infamous of it's internet filtering. This is an article by SF on how it attempts to optimize for China. I can't say this is 100% sure your issue but if it is, you can't fix it unfortunately.